# How to create new Building Configuration in OpenShift (for Django app)

Tags: django, openshift, openshift-nextgen

I need to create a customized building configuration for my **OpenShift(NextGen) Django** application .Currently I am having **django-psql-persistent** configuration, which is comes with **OpenShift(NextGen)-Django** by default.

Comment: What do you mean by customised build configuration? Can you explain in more detail what your requirements are?

Comment: something like, Without **postgresql** database configuration.

Comment: Did you try selecting just 'python' in the catalog when adding the application to the project? It will deploy without a database and still understands Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic 'python' builder image available from the catalog when adding to a project from the web console. You can also use `oc new-app python~<repo-url>` from the command line using the `oc` client.

For examples of a few Django applications set up to use a production WSGI server see:

- https://gitlab.com/osevg/python-django-modwsgi
- https://gitlab.com/osevg/python-django-gunicorn
- https://gitlab.com/osevg/python-django-uwsgi

The repos provide some instructions of deploying the examples and how to set appropriate environment variables.