# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'application' could not be loaded

Tags: python, django, openshift, wsgi, openshift-nextgen

The scenario is,

I cloned the Django code for OpenShift-V3 from [here](https://github.com/openshift/django-ex) . When I ran the code with `python manage.py runserver`, I got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application
> 'application' could not be loaded; Error importing module:
> 'application doesn't look like a module path

I didn't add anything to the code and the required packages are already satisfied.

Comment: Really suggest you use the sample Django applications I pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431684/how-to-create-new-building-configuration-in-openshift-for-django-app They haven't been reorganised and are basically what you get when using ``startproject``. They also explain what was changed to make them align better with OpenShift V3 and how it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to django-ex/project/settings.py

Change the line in **settings.py** as below

`WSGI_APPLICATION = 'application'`  **to**  `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'`

That's it :(

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I am getting the same error and even tried to be more specific and added the specific project.wsgi.application but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 50):

I used a middleware CorsMiddleware but forget to install it so after install, it works perfectly.

`pip install django-cors-headers`

So check something like it you may miss something like it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just double check all your `middleware`!

Answer (score 32):

Read carefully, it might say "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: ...". And the "above exception" being you forgot to install whitehoise. Run `pip install whitenoise`, it worked for me.

Comment: Or, in my case, I had upgraded Django (from 2.2.2 to 3.0.4) but hadn't upgraded whitenoise yet. Once I updated whitenoise (from 4.1.2 to 5.0.1) to the latest version, this error went away.

Comment: A new upgrade of whitenoise broke my application.  There are explicit instructions to update your app here http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0

Answer (score 18):

If you run django project locally for development, just remove WSGI_APPLICATION variable from settings.py module. It needs in prod/stage settings, for example settings_prod.py

Comment: This helped me to find the module that caused the issue. For me it were old paths for the middlewares.

Comment: Just like @LonnyT said it really helped me to see which module is causing this issue

Comment: This help me to track down typo  error in my middleware. Thanks

Comment: Ditto. My issue was syntax on the middleware definitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## Do you have Django Debug Toolbar

Remove it and check if the problem goes away. Possible occurences:

```
pip uninstall django-debug-toolbar

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'debug_toolbar',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

Install this if you didn't before:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

in settings.py add :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem for me - on a totally different project - was to read the actual stack trace which indicates that `whitenoise` was missing.

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Although solved my problem. Generally produced while we are moving a project to different virtual enviroments. Sometimes we forgot to install the package & whitenoise just broke the application little bit, because no where it is mentioned that you are missing "whitenoise" module.

Answer (score 3):

in settings.py file
change as follows:

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'your_project_name.wsgi.application'

Comment: WSGI_APPLICATION = 'edx_django_utils.wsgi.application'

I have done same but still getting the same error

as

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.

Answer (score 3):

note that any error in importing modules anywhere prior to starting the wsgi application will also prompt this message, so first look at the trace and start from the top in fixing issues.

I ported a Django app from python 2.7 to python3 and add all sorts of module import issues, not connected to this issue directly.

Answer (score 3):

Check your middleware and delete error string

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

```py
raise ImportError(
    ImportError: Module "django.middleware.locale" does not define a "LocaleMiddlewarez" attribute/class
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using django-cors-headers, then I thought I haven't implemented cors in my project, so went ahead to install django-cors-middleware, then it's started giving the wsgi exception, so i checked the stack trace and I found out that it's django-cors-headers and django-cors-middleware conflicting each other. I had to uninstall django-cors-middleware but it's still gives the same exception, so uninstall django-cors-headers too then reinstall and everything works fine....

Answer (score 2):

Same problem..
I checked whether django-cors-middleware and django-cors-headers installed or not. I found those were not installed and then I installed them.

1. python -m pip install django-cors-middleware
2. python -m pip install django-cors-headers

Then,

1. python manage.py migrate
2. python manage.py runserver

Finally, it's worked....

Answer (score 2):

Go to `settings.py` :

- In MIDDLEWARE, check whether you have added anything which is not working.
- In INSTALLED_APPS, check whether you have added the apps or not. If not, add all the apps you have created for this project.

Example: I had this error today and was totally unaware why is this happening then after checking for a while, I have found a very silly mistake e.g. I have added my newly created app in the MIDDLEWARE instead of INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Django, to add your app in installed apps in `settings.py` file, write -

[
....,
'`<appname>.apps.<Appname>Config`',
]

where `<Appname>Config` is the name of the function in the `apps.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have entered your module name correctly in the **setting.py** or you may have added it incorrectly in wrong place like middleware...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31524863)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these solution and the one worked for me was this:

```
pip install django-htmlmin
```

This module was missing and not mentioned in requirements.txt
Shows long error message that ends with wsgi application improperly configured. But somewhere in middle I could see `"No module named 'htmlmin'` I installed and it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

maybe using middleware is the simple way to fix this , this problem mostly happens about **cors Policy**

**Code**:

```
class CorsMiddleware(object):
   def __init__(self, get_response):
      self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
      return self.get_response(request)

   def process_response(self,resp):
      resp["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
      return resp
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you insert something in MIDDLEWARE = [......]
solution tire to put added latest addend things at top of middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this error while adding your custom middleware. While adding it, make sure you so it like this:
folder_contains_your_middleware_file.middleware_file.middleware_class

Below is my example:

```
'company_management.loginCheckMiddleware.LoginCheckMiddleware'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, in spite of trying all the above solutions I was facing the same issue.
I noticed that before this error I was getting the below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log_request_id'
```

To resolve this error I installed the `django-log-request-id` package using `pip install django-log-request-id` and both the issues got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the custom middleware, but forgot to exclude it from `MIDDLEWARES` in the `settings.py` module, so be sure to verify that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the logs, the same error was thrown due to a `"WhitenoiseMiddleware"` error, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503261/importerror-module-whitenoise-middleware-does-not-define-a-whitenoisemiddlew).

The way to solve it was to **make sure that `WhiteNoiseMiddleware` is placed directly after the Django `SecurityMiddleware`** (if you are using it) and before all other middleware.
In `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',  # <-- here
  # ...
]
```

Check the [Django documentation](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#enable-whitenoise) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me

```
 MIDDLEWARE = [
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # add only comma 
    ]
```

My CORS Configuration

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CROS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, in my case, the project dependency: `django-request-logging` was not installed. This was resulting in the same error

`pipenv install`

installed the dependency and fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your app name written in

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
...
'App_name', 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a number of issues. Just confirm:

1. If you are using gunicorn to server you django app ensure **Whitenose** is installed,and added to your middlewares and your gunicorn command lookes something like `gunicorn APP-NAME.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 120 --workers 2 --log-level info` and ensure your settings.py has something like`WSGI_APPLICATION = "APP-NAME.wsgi.application"`
2. If above is correct or you ain`t using gunicorn. Kindly check your middlewares. Most of the time you might have a middleware thats not installed that maybe blocking the server from starting.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' from MIDDLEWARE. This worked for me when I had similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if that's the case but personally I had the same error and the problem was just a typo in the middlewares, I wrote corseheaders (with an extra "e") instead of corsheaders

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Django 4.2 / Django 5.0 in `settings.py` I had to change

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ubereats_tracker.wsgi.app'
```

to

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ubereats_tracker.wsgi.application'
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are in desired ***python Environment***

> Get the `requirements.txt` file or the `python modules list`, which are needed to execute django.

Install all the Modules and you shall be good to go.